# Is there a way to convert Video DVD to multiple disk of VCD?

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, vcd

as title, how can i convert a video DVD (4.1GB) and burn it into multiple disk of VCDs (7xx MB)?

Do I need to convert into ISO image first? or make it as AVI ?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you want to break up the movie and have it span several VCDs?  To put it another way, you could Rip the movie from the DVD convert it to a movie file small enough to fit on a single VCD, and then make your VCD... if you were so inclined.

It's not so much a matter of converting the original movie to an AVI.  The original movie on the DVD is actually in MPEG-2 format on the disc.  Yep.  Those VOB files on the disc are really just MPG files.  You could open them with an MPG editor, edit them, and save them locally if you wanted, without any conversion at all.  VCDs use the older MPEG-1 format.  So, in the end, you are going to have to convert from MPEG-2 to MPEG-1.  Not THAT much of a big deal, actually.  But adding a ton of steps in between will just really affect the quality of the end result.

THAT said... [there are a number of easily available tools to convert a DVD to VCD.](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/sections/dvd-to-vcd-svcd)  Videohelp.com is your friend in this case.  Tutorials, links to software with explanations, etc.

Comment: It is because I just have the VCD player at my home and I want to watch through that VCD player. Is the format playable in VCD player, any concern?
In all, so convert the DVD file to multiple MPG1 and then burn it into separate disk?

Comment: If you don't want to use software that will convert a single DVD into a single VCD, then you will most likely have to handle this manually... meaning you will be ripping the DVD onto a hard drive, converting the MPEG-2 movie into an MPEG-1 movie, opening it in an MPEG editor, selecting 700mb chunks of it, and saving them as individual MPEG-1 files... and then making a disc out of each one.  That is, unless you find a piece of software that will allow you to span a DVD across several VCDs automatically.

Comment: Ya get your point, so for your softwares recommended in your link, are they able to convert 1 DVD into 1 single VCD automatically and magically?

Comment: No.  The software available at the link will simply make the conversion from DVD VOB files to a single VCD MPEG movie file easier.  As in... you put the DVD in the optical drive, start DVD2VCD (for example), tell it where the DVD is, tell it you want a VCD, and let it do it's thing.  You will still need burning software to actually make the VCD disc out of the VCD file.  But... that's about as easy as it is going to get without purchasing a software suite like Ulead that will REALLY automate everything for you.

Comment: after I rip a vob file, is it ok just burn to vcd?

Comment: in all my comments, what would make you think it was OK to just burn the VOB files to a VCD?  I mean, I realize you are "just askin", but I did state that DVDs use a different kind of MPEG file from a VCD, and I did state that you will have to convert from the MPEG-2 file the DVD uses, to the MPEG-1 file the VCD uses... and the VOB files will most like be 1gb in size, which will be too large to put on a 700mb CD.  So, based on what I've already said, the answer would be *No*.